# Basic question: Querying data and performance tradeoffs

Tags: mysql, database, json, database-design

Let's say I have 100 rows in my table, with 3 columns of numbers. I don't need all the rows, only about half of them every time I fetch data. I only want the rows that have updated as getting the rest would be redundant.

Is it better to add a field and give it a datetime field to represent that it has updated since the last time I've fetched it (and use that as a criteria when SELECTing)? Or would it be better to simply download all the data each and every time (currently the data is being sent back as a JSON file).

What are the tradeoffs in terms of speed, bandwidth usage, and server cpu usage between these two options? Is the former just plain better than the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Jens Struwe and roycl are right - but as you're asking a hypothetical question, you're going to get answers that are right *and* contradictory.

If only half the data is relevant, how is the client going to determine which data to show? If the decision can be made by software at all, it's more efficient to do it on the database - but it's also more logical.

With tables of 100 rows, performance is neither here nor there; maintainability and long-term upgradability is a far bigger deal. Most developers would expect a logical database design, and sorting/filtering to be done on the DB rather than the client.

Answer (score 1):

Always (or at least if possible) select only data that you need to accomplish your task. Vice versa: Never select data that you have to filter out. In result: Add a timestamp field for the updates and select only these rows whose timestamp is > than the given one.

Answer (score 1):

With a 100 rows in your table and 3 columns of numbers it really doesn't matter which approach you use if you don't mind if the server returns the data in less than a few 10s of milliseconds. The rows, if queried frequently, will all be in memory anyway. It also makes your json code simpler and your client code dumber (which is probably good, and more maintainable).

If you had a several-million row table with only a small percentage of data that was required, you would naturally want to limit the return set, and the easiest way of doing that is with an SQL `WHERE` clause, such as `WHERE dt_modified > my_timestamp`. On a properly optimised database even this query could come in at well under 100ms.

The issue may be more to do with time the data spends "on the wire", how much time the client spends either regenerating the page, or updating it based on the returned data. Client processing tim is often the slowest part of the process. Only testing on different browsers and over different network speeds will find the best balance between server-side tweeks, network fixes (such as gzipping to compress data) and optimising your javascript calls.